# Simple object insertion using MongoDB and MongoJack

Tags: java, mongodb, jackson, mongojack

I'm trying to follow the [MongoJack tutorial](http://mongojack.org/tutorial.html) but I'm failing the first task: Inserting an object into the database.

This is what I have:

```
DB db = new MongoClient().getDB("mydb");

JacksonDBCollection<MyDomainObject, String> coll =
    JacksonDBCollection.wrap(db.getCollection("coll"),
                             MyDomainObject.class,
                             String.class);

MyDomainObject obj = new MyDomainObject(ObjectId.get().toString(), 123456789L);

WriteResult<MyDomainObject, String> result = coll.insert(obj);

System.out.println(result.getSavedId());
```

Where `MyDomainObject` class looks as follows:

```
class MyDomainObject {

    // @org.mongojack.ObjectId  doesn't work
    public String id;
    public long someValue;

    public MyDomainObject(String id, long someValue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

}
```

With the above code I end up with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

And I can't for my life figure out why. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently all I had to do was to rename

```
public String id;
```

to

```
public String _id;
```

(Annotating the field with `@JsonProperty("_id")` also seems to do the trick. AFAICT there's no way of saying that `public String id` should *replace* the `_id` field. If someone knows how to do this, I'm interested in how.

Answer (score 1):

You could also annotate any String field with @org.mongojack.Id.
This worked for me.